# Lotto/lucky draw

Tags: php, html, random

The following script draws 6 numbers at random.

I input another 6 numbers and compare with random numbers generated, if they're the same, you win.

```
    <html>
<body>

<form align="center" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

Numele jucatorului <input type="text" name="nume" min="1" max="10" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 1: <input type="number" name="nr1" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 2: <input type="number" name="nr2" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 3: <input type="number" name="nr3" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 4: <input type="number" name="nr4" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 5: <input type="number" name="nr5" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
Numar 6: <input type="number" name="nr6" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit">
<br>

<form>


<?php
#error_reporting(0);

$server = "";
$user = "";
$password = "";


$conectare = new mysqli($server, $user, $password);


if ($conectare->connect_error){
        die("Conexiune esuata:" . $conectare->connect_error);
}



$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nume"]);
$rn1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr1"]);
$rn2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr2"]);
$rn3 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr3"]);
$rn4 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr4"]);
$rn5 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr5"]);
$rn6 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr6"]);
echo "<br>Salut " . $name . "!<br>";
echo "<br>Numerele introduse sunt:" . $rn1 . " " . $rn2 . " " . $rn3 . " " . $rn4 . " " . $rn5 . " " . $rn6 . "<br>";


$numere = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49);
$random = array_rand($numere, 6);
$nr1 = $numere[$random[0]];
$nr2 = $numere[$random[1]];
$nr3 = $numere[$random[2]];
$nr4 = $numere[$random[3]];
$nr5 = $numere[$random[4]];
$nr6 = $numere[$random[5]];
$extrase = array($nr1, $nr2, $nr3, $nr4, $nr5, $nr6);
echo "Numerele extrase sunt:" . $nr1 . " " . $nr2 . " " . $nr3 . " " . $nr4 . " " . $nr5 . " " . $nr6 . "<br>";



if ($nr1 == $rn1 or $nr1 == $rn2 or $nr1 == $rn3 or $nr1 == $rn4 or $nr1 == $rn5 or $nr1 == $rn6){
        echo "Castigator : $nr1 " ;
}
if ($nr2 == $rn1 or $nr2 == $rn2 or $nr2 == $rn3 or $nr2 == $rn4 or $nr2 == $rn5 or $nr2 == $rn6){
        echo "Numar castigator : $nr2 " ;
}
if ($nr3 == $rn1 or $nr3 == $rn2 or $nr3 == $rn3 or $nr3 == $rn4 or $nr3 == $rn5 or $nr3 == $rn6){
        echo "Numar castigator : $nr3 " ;
}
if ($nr4 == $rn1 or $nr4 == $rn2 or $nr4 == $rn3 or $nr4 == $rn4 or $nr4 == $rn5 or $nr4 == $rn6){
        echo "Numar castigator : $nr4 " ;
}
if ($nr5 == $rn1 or $nr5 == $rn2 or $nr5 == $rn3 or $nr5 == $rn4 or $nr5 == $rn5 or $nr5 == $rn6){
        echo "Numar castigator : $nr5 " ;
}
if ($nr6 == $rn1 or $nr6 == $rn2 or $nr6 == $rn3 or $nr6 == $rn4 or $nr6 == $rn5 or $nr6 == $rn6){
        echo "Numar castigator : $nr6 " ;
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do to improve your code.

1. You should try to seperate your logic from your html. In larger applications this will mean seprate files (probably following an MVC convention), but for small scripts like this simply placing your logic at the top of the file before the html is a good idea.
2. You need to use a conditional check to make sure the form has been posted before trying to access the posted values. This can be done by checking the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable.
3. Instead of using individual form field names for related data, you can use the array syntax `name="somename[]"` note the square braces. Then php will gather the data from the separate fields into a single array held in `$_POST['somename']`.
4. Builing on from @Quill's answer, you can simplify the generation of the random answers further by using `array_flip` to transpose the result of `range` into an array indexed from 1-49 then use the keys returned by `array_rand` directly
5. You can simplify calculating matching results by using `array_interect` to retrieve an array for matches

Putting this all together:

```
<?php
$showResults = false;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $showResults = true;

    $name = $_POST['nume'];
    $answers = $_POST['nr'];

    $randomAnswers = array_rand(array_flip(range(1, 49)), 6);

    $matches = array_intersect($answers, $randomAnswers);
    $numberOfMatches = count($matches);
}

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

        Your name: <input type="text" name="nume" min="1" max="10" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 1: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 2: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 3: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 4: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 5: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        Number 6: <input type="number" name="nr[]" min="1" max="49" required="yes"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
        <br>

    <form>

        <?php
        if($showResults):?>
            <p>Hello <?php echo $name;?>!<p>
            <p>Your lotto numbers are: <?php echo implode(' ', $answers);?></p>

            <p>The winning numbers are: <?php echo implode(' ', $randomAnswers);?></p>
            <p>You matched (<?php echo $numberOfMatches;?>) numbers</p>
            <?php
            if($numberOfMatches == 6):?>
                <h1>Congratulations you won the Lotto!</h1>
            <?php
            endif;
        endif;
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using arrays and loops in your code rather than repeating yourself over and over.

---

You should consider turning the hard-to-understand variables like `$rn6` into something more reader-friendly, and easier to understand.

---

The following block could be converted from manually reading the elements into an array:

> ```
> $rn1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr1"]);
> $rn2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr2"]);
> $rn3 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr3"]);
> $rn4 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr4"]);
> $rn5 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr5"]);
> $rn6 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr6"]);
> ```

into:

```
$inputtedAnswers = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++){
    $inputtedAnswers[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nr" . $i]);
}
```

---

You could take your long `echo` statement, and turn in into an array join, with the function [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> ```
> echo "<br>Numerele introduse sunt:" . $rn1 . " " . $rn2 . " " . $rn3 . " " . $rn4 . " " . $rn5 . " " . $rn6 . "<br>";
> ```

into:

```
echo "<br>Numerele introduse sunt:" . implode(" ", $inputtedAnswers) . "</br>";
```

---

Instead of having a reaaaaaaaally long range block, let's use a similarly named function: [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

> ```
> $numere = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49);
> ```

```
$numere = range(1, 49);
```

Actually, in fact, let's get rid of `$numere` altogether because as it seems, your `$nr*` values are simply `$random[*] + 1`.

```
$random = array_rand(range(1, 49), 6);
$nr1 = $random[0] + 1;
```

Let's even do one step further and turn this into a loop:

```
$randomAnswers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    $randomAnswers[] = $random[$i] + 1;
}
```

Which eliminates the purpose of `$extrase`, which as it seems, was unused anyway.

---

Onto the `if` statement, rather than manually testing each variable up against each variable, use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops:

> ```
> if ($nr1 == $rn1 or $nr1 == $rn2 or $nr1 == $rn3 or $nr1 == $rn4 or $nr1 == $rn5 or $nr1 == $rn6){
>         echo "Castigator : $nr1 " ;
> }
> if ($nr2 == $rn1 or $nr2 == $rn2 or $nr2 == $rn3 or $nr2 == $rn4 or $nr2 == $rn5 or $nr2 == $rn6){
>         echo "Numar castigator : $nr2 " ;
> }
> if ($nr3 == $rn1 or $nr3 == $rn2 or $nr3 == $rn3 or $nr3 == $rn4 or $nr3 == $rn5 or $nr3 == $rn6){
>         echo "Numar castigator : $nr3 " ;
> }
> if ($nr4 == $rn1 or $nr4 == $rn2 or $nr4 == $rn3 or $nr4 == $rn4 or $nr4 == $rn5 or $nr4 == $rn6){
>         echo "Numar castigator : $nr4 " ;
> }
> if ($nr5 == $rn1 or $nr5 == $rn2 or $nr5 == $rn3 or $nr5 == $rn4 or $nr5 == $rn5 or $nr5 == $rn6){
>         echo "Numar castigator : $nr5 " ;
> }
> if ($nr6 == $rn1 or $nr6 == $rn2 or $nr6 == $rn3 or $nr6 == $rn4 or $nr6 == $rn5 or $nr6 == $rn6){
>         echo "Numar castigator : $nr6 " ;
> }
> ```

You have over-indented the `echo` lines, and there shouldn't be a space before your semicolon.

To convert this into a working `foreach` statement, you could do the following:

```
foreach ($inputtedAnswers as $inputtedValue){
    if (in_array($inputtedValue, $randomAnswers)){
        echo("Numar castigator: " . $inputtedValue);
    //  break;
    }
}
```

If you want this to only print one answer instead of a possible maximum of six, you can just uncomment out the `break` inside the `if` statement.

---

Your code also needs reformatting as both the HTML and the PHP are formatted incorrectly.